# Is there a way to get user input from BotFramework inside a loop

Tags: c#, botframework

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            // Global variables
            var boolAskedForFName = false;
            var boolAskedForLName = false;
            var userLName = string.Empty;
            var userFName = string.Empty;

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

                // Get any saved values
                var sc = activity.GetStateClient();
                var userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(
                    activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
                boolAskedForCity = userData.GetProperty<bool>("AskedForUserFName");
                boolAskedForName = userData.GetProperty<bool>("AskedForUserLName");
                userLName = userData.GetProperty<string>("LastName") ?? "";
                userFName = userData.GetProperty<string>("FirstName") ?? "";

                if (boolAskedForFName == false)
                {
                    Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply("May i have your first name?");
                    replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
                    replyToConversation.Type = "message";

                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("AskedForUserFName", true);

                    var reply = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyToConversation);
                }
                else if (boolAskedForLName == false) 
                {
                    userName = activity.Text;
                    userData.SetProperty<string>("Name", userFName);

                    var replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply("what about last name?");
                    replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
                    replyToConversation.Type = "message";
                    replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("AskedForUserLName", true);

                    var reply = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyToConversation);
                }
                else
                {                   
                }
                // Save BotUserData
                sc.BotState.SetPrivateConversationData(
                    activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id, userData);
            }           
        }
```

I cannot come up with better way. This seems like very bad design. 
Flaws -> I ask for first name in first if loop but i get the output back in second else if loop. 
If i follow this conversation for a while i will have code that will be unmanageable. Is there a better way of doing this? I was thinking of using dialog but just wanted to put code out there to see if someone did this in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FormFlow:

FormFlow class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProfileForm
{
    // these are the fields that will hold the data
    // we will gather with the form
    [Prompt("What is your first name? {||}")]
    public string FirstName;
    [Prompt("What is your last name? {||}")]
    public string LastName;
    [Prompt("What is your gender? {||}")]
    public Gender Gender;
    // This method 'builds' the form 
    // This method will be called by code we will place
    // in the MakeRootDialog method of the MessagesControlller.cs file
    public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to the profile bot!")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                {
                    // Tell the user that the form is complete
                    await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
                })
                .Build();
    }
}
// This enum provides the possible values for the 
// Gender property in the ProfileForm class
// Notice we start the options at 1 
[Serializable]
public enum Gender
{
    Male = 1, Female = 2
};
```

Controller:

```
internal static IDialog<ProfileForm> MakeRootDialog()
{
    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(ProfileForm.BuildForm));
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    // Detect if this is a Message activity
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        // Call our FormFlow by calling MakeRootDialog
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialog);
    }
    else
    {
        // This was not a Message activity
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    // Return response
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;            
}
```

See:
[Introduction To FormFlow With The Microsoft Bot Framework](http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/8/Introduction-To-FormFlow-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework)

Comment: How will we save state in this? Also if i need to incorporate another logic lets say give user input from a api to select news they want to see i wont be able to do that with form flow right?

Comment: See the end of the article: Introduction To FormFlow With The Microsoft Bot Framework (http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/8/Introduction-To-FormFlow-With-The-Microsoft-Bot-Framework) for an example of saving data.